# Files displaying in File Manager even though they don't exist

Tags: file-manager

I must have at some point manually deleted images via FTP in my image file directories.

In the file manager, even after 'syncing' the directory, those files that no longer exist are still displayed. If I try to delete the rows, it shows an error:

```
File /var/sites/domain.com/public_html/images/uploads/galleries/filename.jpg does not exist.
```

How can I remove these?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Experiencing the same after files were deleted via FTP.

Comment: +1 same issue EE2.11.1

Comment: +1 same here 3.3.3

Comment: have a look in the thumbs directory? or manipulations directory too?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried 'sync'ing'? I believe this updates the database with the actual content of folders (and creates any manipulations that may exist).